# "White-side" meaning "from all flanks"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, word-in-context, word-meaning

ContextReverso website, when I input "**со всех флангов**" returns an English translation "**white-side**" (*possibly as adverb*), which they state means "**from all flanks**".

Is it a special military term or is it complete rubbish?

What is the correct term for "**from all flanks**" or what does military use in such case?

P.s. "***on/from*** all flanks" is correct?

Comment: I never heard of ***white-side*** except with the sense given by [OED's definition](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/412589) of the adjective *Having sides of a white or pale colour; marked with white along the side or flank.* Are you sure you're not looking for [**blindside**?](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blindside)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, I was looking for English version of "**from all flanks**" translated from Russian, but somehow "**white-side**" popped up as a translation.

Comment: You can say *on all flanks* or *from all flanks*, the former specifying the places of the attacks, the latter, the directions whence the attackers are coming.

Comment: Okay, I think [this is where it comes from](https://www.quora.com/In-American-Sniper-film-the-terms-white-side-and-green-side-are-used-during-a-combat-scene-What-do-they-mean): *In American Sniper (film), the terms white side and green side are used during a combat scene. What do they mean?* It's apparently based on the conventional colour of nautical lights (red, green, white = port, starboard, stern). But I'd stick to *attacked **from the rear*** (or ***from behind***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On all sides" or "From all sides" is what I would use (as a non-military American).

> They have us surrounded on all sides.
>
> They are attacking from all sides.

If you are not looking specifically for military jargon, that is a way to phrase it that would make sense and not sound strange (at least in my area).

Answer (score 1):

***A flank***, meaning one of the two sides of a military formation, can be either right or left (also southern or northern/eastern or western). So in the context of the attack on the opposing army "to attack (on) all(?) flanks" sounds rather odd in comparison to "[to attack (on) both flanks](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attack+on+both+flanks%2Cattack+both+flanks%2Cattack+on+all+flanks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattack%20on%20both%20flanks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattack%20both%20flanks%3B%2Cc0)". Note  the use of preposition "on" where you can't do without it, for example:

> They decided to attack their enemy's southern flank.
>
> The army was attacked on the left flank.

In the context of [flanking maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanking_maneuver), you can use the verb [outflank](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/outflank), which also can be used  figuratively meaning *get the better of*. ([See the examples in different contexts](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22outflank%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=-D6gWvyPOsvm6ASPuKTwBg)).

In addition:

If it's frontal, from the rear, and flanking, all  at the same time, the attack would be an [attack from/on all sides](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attack+from+all+sides%2Cattack+on+all+sides&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattack%20from%20all%20sides%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattack%20on%20all%20sides%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't heard of "white-side" except literally (having white sides). There is a reasonably common word "blindside", which is used as a verb mean "To attack from behind" or "to ambush".

Apparently there is a military use. Ships use lights, with red on the left, green on the right and white on the back. Hence "white-side" means on the back. It is not in common use.